# Does lftp support SOCKS proxy?

Tags: linux, proxy, ftp

I am trying to use lftp with SOCKS proxy
I can't find any documents or experience when googling. 
Any suggestion will be appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: IIRC the socks proxy is fairly transparent, but you have to use FTP in "passive" mode (possibly the `ftp:passive-mode` option in `lftp`)

Comment: Given that it is not [documented](https://lftp.yar.ru/lftp-man.html) to support a SOCKS proxy but it is documented to support a HTTP proxy it is very likely that it does not have inherent support for SOCKS proxy. And contrary what xenoid said a SOCKS proxy is not fairly transparent: there is some handshake at the start of each TCP connection which need to be done for both the control and the data  connections. There are tools like [socksify](https://linux.die.net/man/1/socksify) though which try to provide SOCKS support for applications which don't have any inherent support for it.